# How to format the length of all lines in a text file

Tags: python, file, format

If there was a text file in which each line might have a different length, how would one format each line of the file to be a certain number of characters in length?

For example, turn

```
>Letters of the alphabet
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

to

```
>Letters of the alphabet
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
UVWXY
Z
```

and so on as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: Even though the linked dupe is for `lists` it still works for `strings` as well.

Comment: Yep, didn't see that article. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

max_length = int(input("Max length of your line = "))

file = open("file.txt","r") #open the file to edit and read the data
content = file.read()
file.close()

file_out = open("file_out.txt","w+") #create the output file

for i in range(len(content)):
    file_out.write(content[i])
    if (i + 1) % max_length == 0: #add line break each time pgcd equal 0
         file_out.write('\n')
file_out.close()
```